Expectation of uniformly distributed random variables on unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{N}$
This question is basically a continuation (generalization ) of another query already asked.
So the setup to consider a random complex vector $x = (x_{1},\cdots, x_{N})$ uniformly distributed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{N}$. I would like to find the value of
$M_{2}= E[|x_{1}|^{2}]$ and $M_{4} = E[|x_{1}|^{4}]$.
The above-posted question already answers in a satisfactory manner what would happen for the case of real vector in $R^{N}$.
Repeating the same for complex case it is straightforward to obtain the $M_{2}= \frac{1}{N}$.
However, I am a bit stuck in the calculation of $M_{4}$. It is if I repeat the same procedure as for real, I would get the same result which wrong as can be found here. But the answer given here is missing a key point in the derivation which is the relation $$ M_{4} = 2 V_{12}$$
where $V_{12}= E[|x_{1}|^{2} |x_{2}|^{2}]$.
As a first step we repeat the calculation for the case of real and we obtain $$N M_{4} + N (N-1)V_{12} = 1 $$. This can be obtained by squaring the relation $\sum_{i}x_{i}^{2} =1 $ and doing proper replacements.
To derive another equation relating $M_{4}$ and $V_{12}$, I set out to proceed as in the case of reals again. We note that
$(x_{1}, x_{2})$ and $\left(\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{x_{1}-x_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$  are identically distributed and thus we have $$ E[\frac{|(x_{1}+x_{2})|^{2}|(x_{1}-x_{2})|^{2}}{4} = E[|x_{1}^{2}||x_{2}^{2}|] $$
now since each of the numbers here is complex so I can write $x_{k} = a_{k}+ i b_{k}$, I can substitute it back and if I now follow the procedure then I get $$E(a^{4})= 2 E[a_{1}^{2} a_{2}^{2}]$$ where now we notice that $a$ denotes any real number in the space $R^{2n}$. But since $|x_{1}|^{2}$ is also one such real number so this relation also means that $M_{4} = 2 V_{12}$. Substituting this in the previous relation obtained for $M_{4}$ and $V_{12}$ I thus obtain  $$E[|x_{1}|^{4}] = \frac{2}{N(N+1)}$$
which as I know is correct. However I am not able to convince myself of the last bit of the calculation where I argue $M_{4} = 2 V_{12}$, so I would like to know if it is correct or not? Or more importantly is there another way to derive $M_{4}$? Thank you so much in advance.

What is the relation between $n$ and $N$?

I am extremely sorry for this, it should not be $n$ but just $N$ everywhere. I have corrected it now

Ok. Now what is $|x|^2$? If you mean $|x|^2=|x_1|^2+\cdots+|x_N|^2$ since it is one, there is nothing to do.

I am sorry again ( and the trouble). What I need to find is $E[|x_{1}|^{4}]$. And yes what you said for $|x|^{2}$ is true.

The unit ball of $C^N$ is the unit ball of $R^{2N}.$ The uniform distribution on the unit sphere of $R^d$ is the distribution of $Z/\|Z\|$ where $Z\sim N(0,I_d).$ If $X_1=a_1+ib_1\in C$ then the distribution of $|X_1|^2$ is the distribution of
$$\frac{Z_1^2+Z_2^2}{Z_1^2+Z_2^2+\ldots+Z^2_{2N}},$$ with $d=2N$. Since $Z_i^2/2$ gamma distributed with scale parameter $1/2$ then $|X_1|^2$ is beta distributed with parameters $1$ and $N-1$ using the fact that $A/(A+B)\sim \beta(a,b)$ when $A\sim \Gamma(a)$ and $B\sim \Gamma(b)$ are independent. The expectation of $|X_1|^4$ is $B(3,N-1)/B(1,N-1)=2/(N^2+N)$ as you predicted.

Thank you so much for the help.
